# .rbenv-vars has gone after git pull

Tags: git

With my rails app. I did "git pull" for updating the app.

The problem is I did "git add ." and "git commit -m "some message"" before git pull but didn't push it.

Then, .rbenv-vars in the server has gone after "git pull origin master"

```
* branch            some_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 222fd45..bf9932c
Fast-forward
 .DS_Store                                                 | Bin 14340 -> 14340 bytes
 .rbenv-vars                                               |   9 -
 Gemfile                                                   |   2 +
 Gemfile.lock                                              |  40 +++++
```

I tried git reset HEAD@{1} for retrieving the .rbenv-vars but couldn't.

Do you have any idea for retrieving .rbenv-vars again?

Comment: After all, I couldn't restore the data. Overall, the biggest issue here is the .rbenv_vars is not included in .gitignore. Since .rbenv_vars has many sensitive information, it should be at least encrypted. So, currently I'm creating .rbenv_vars file through Ansible. Also, those infos are encrypted by ansible vault.